# Using a timing based PollingConsumer to a direct endpoint

Tags: java, apache-camel

Functionally I wish to check a URL is active before I consume from a JMS (WMQ) endpoint.
If the URL cannot be reached or a server error, then I do not want to pick up from the queue.  So I want to keep trying (with unlimited retries) the URL via a polling consumer. So as soon as it is available I can pick up from JMS.

I have a RouteBuilder that is set up with a direct endpoint, that is configured to run a Processor that will ping a service.

So:

```
public class PingRoute extends RouteBuilder {
        @Override
        public void configureCamel() {
            from("direct:pingRoute").routeId(PingRoute.class.getSimpleName())
                .process(new PingProcessor(url))
                .to("log://PingRoute?showAll=true");
        }
    }
```

In another route I am setting up my timer:

```
    @Override
public void configureCamel() {
       from(timerEndpoint).beanRef(PollingConsumerBean.class.getSimpleName(), "checkPingRoute");
   ...
    }
```

And with the `PollingConsumerBean` I am attempting to receive the body via a consumer:

```
public void checkPingRoute(){
    // loop to check the consumer.  Check we can carry on with the pick up from the JMS queue.
    while(true){
        Boolean pingAvailable = consumer.receiveBody("direct:pingRoute", Boolean.class);
   ...
    }
```

I add the route to the context and use a producer to send:

```
context.addRoutes(new PingRoute());
context.start();
producer.sendBody(TimerPollingRoute.TIMER_POLLING_ROUTE_ENDPOINT, "a body");
```

And I get the following `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
Cannot add a 2nd consumer to the same endpoint. Endpoint Endpoint[direct://pingRoute] only allows one consumer.
```

Is there a way to setup the direct route as a polling consumer?

Comment: Could you please describe what you are trying to achieve in a funcional way? It's hard to grasp from your code. I feel the below answers are chugging along rather than helping you rethink your solution towards a simpler and more optimal design.

Comment: Yup fair enough.  Have now added the functionality I am after.
Have got around the 2nd Consumer problem by using a processor rather than a direct route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the answers here pointed me on the right direction but I finally came up with a solution that managed to fit our code base and framework.

Firstly, I discovered there isn't a need to have bean to act as a polling consumer but a processor could be used instead.

```
@Override
public void configureCamel() {
    from("timer://fnzPoller?period=2000&delay=2000").processRef(UrlPingProcessor.class.getSimpleName())
           .processRef(StopStartProcessor.class.getSimpleName()).to("log://TimerPollingRoute?showAll=true");

}
```

Then in the `UrlPingProcessor` there is CXF service to ping the url and can check the response :

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) {
    try {
        // CXF service
        FnzPingServiceImpl fnzPingService = new FnzPingServiceImpl(url);
        fnzPingService.getPing();
    } catch (WebApplicationException e) {
        int responseCode = e.getResponse().getStatus();
        boolean isValidResponseCode = ResponseCodeUtil.isResponseCodeValid(responseCode);
        if (!isValidResponseCode) {
            // Sets a flag to stop for the StopStartProcessor
            stopRoute(exchange);
        }
    } 
}
```

Then in the `StopStartProcessor` it is using a `ExecutorService` to stop or start a route via new thread.:

```
    @Override
public void process(final Exchange exchange) {
    // routeBuilder is set on the constructor.
    final String routeId = routeBuilder.getClass().getSimpleName();
    Boolean stopRoute = ExchangeHeaderUtil.getHeader(exchange, Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, Boolean.class);
    boolean stopRoutePrim = BooleanUtils.isTrue(stopRoute);
    if (stopRoutePrim) {
        StopRouteThread stopRouteThread = new StopRouteThread(exchange, routeId);
        executorService.execute(stopRouteThread);
    } else {
        CamelContext context = exchange.getContext();
        Route route = context.getRoute(routeId);
        if (route == null) {
            try {
                context.addRoutes(routeBuilder);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                String msg = "Unable to add a route: " + routeBuilder;
                LOGGER.warn(msg, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Business logic is not quite clear, unfortunately. As I understand it - you need to wait for a response from the service. IMHO you have to use **Content Enricher** EIP http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html . `pollEnrich` is what you need at timer route.

`.pollEnrich("direct:waitForResponce", -1)` or
`.pollEnrich("seda:waitForResponce", -1)`

```
public class PingRoute extends RouteBuilder {
        @Override
        public void configureCamel() {
             from("direct:pingRoute").routeId(PingRoute.class.getSimpleName())
                .process(new PingProcessor(url))
             .choice().when(body())                       
                  .to("log://PingRoute?showAll=true")
                  .to("direct:waitForResponce") 
                .otherwise()
                  .to("direct:pingRoute")
                .end(); 
        }
};
```

timer:

```
    @Override
    public void configureCamel() {                           
      from(timerEndpoint)
      .inOnly("direct:pingRoute")
      .pollEnrich("direct:waitForResponce", -1)
       ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [OP's clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34724504/using-a-timing-based-pollingconsumer-to-a-direct-endpoint?noredirect=1#comment57228783_34724504) of their use case, they have several problems to solve:

- Consume the message from the JMS queue if, and only if, the ping to the URL is *positive*.
- If the URL is unresponsive, the JMS message should not disappear from the queue and a *retry* must take place until the URL becomes responsive again, in which case the message will be ultimately consumed.
- The OP has not specified if the amount of retries is *limited* or *unlimited*.

Based on this problem scenario, I suggest a redesign of their solution that leverages [**ActiveMQ retries**](http://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy.html), [**broker-side redelivery**](http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html#MessageRedeliveryandDLQHandling-BrokerRedelivery(v5.7)) and [**JMS transactions in Camel**](https://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-make-my-jms-endpoint-transactional.html) to:

1. Return the message to the queue if the URL ping failed (via a transaction rollback).
2. Ensure that the message is not lost (by using JMS persistence and broker-side redeliveries, AMQ will durably schedule the retry cycle).
3. Be able to specify a sophisticated retry cycle per message, e.g. with exponential backoffs, maximum retries, etc.
4. Optionally sending the message to a [Dead Letter Queue](http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html) if the retry cycle was exhausted without a positive result, so that some other (possibly manual) action can be planned.

Now, **implementation-wise**:

```
from("activemq:queue:abc?transacted=true")          // (1)
    .to("http4://host.endpoint.com/foo?method=GET") // (2) (3)
    .process(new HandleSuccess());                  // (4)
```

Comments:

1. Note the `transacted` flag.
2. If the HTTP invocation fails, the [HTTP4](https://camel.apache.org/http4.html) endpoint will raise an Exception.
3. Since there are no configured exception handlers, Camel will propagate the exception to the consumer endpoint (`activemq`) which will **rollback** the transaction.
4. If the invocation succeeded, the flow will continue and the exchange body will now contain the payload returned by the HTTP server and you can handle it in whichever way you wish. Here I'm using a processor.

Next, what's important is that you configure the redelivery policy in ActiveMQ, as well as enable broker-side redeliveries. You do that in your `activemq.xml` configuration file:

```
<plugins>
  <redeliveryPlugin fallbackToDeadLetter="true" sendToDlqIfMaxRetriesExceeded="true">
    <redeliveryPolicyMap>
      <redeliveryPolicyMap>
        <redeliveryPolicyEntries>
          <redeliveryPolicy queue="my.queue" 
                            initialRedeliveryDelay="30000" 
                            maximumRedeliveries="17" 
                            maximumRedeliveryDelay="259200000" 
                            redeliveryDelay="30000" 
                            useExponentialBackOff="true"
                            backOffMultiplier="2" />
        </redeliveryPolicyEntries>
      </redeliveryPolicyMap>
    </redeliveryPolicyMap>
  </redeliveryPlugin>
</plugins>
```

And make sure that the scheduler support is enabled in the top-level `<broker />` element:

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" 
        brokerName="mybroker" 
        schedulerSupport="true">
    ...
</broker>
```

I hope that helps.

**EDIT 1:** OP is using IBM WebSphere MQ as a broker, I missed that. You could use a JMS QueueBrowser to peek at messages and try their corresponding URLs before actually consuming a message, but it is not possible to selectively consume an individual message – that's not what MOM (messaging-oriented middleware) is about.

So I insist that you should explore JMS transactions, but rather than leaving it up to the broker to redeliver the message, you can start the pinging cycle to the URL within the TX body itself. With regards to Camel, you could implement it as follows:

```
from("jms:queue:myqueue?transacted=true")
    .bean(new UrlPinger());
```

UrlPinger.java:

```
public class UrlPinger {

    @EndpointInject
    private ProducerTemplate template;

    private Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(http(?:s)?)\\:");

    @Handler
    public void pingUrl(@Body String url, CamelContext context) throws InterruptedException {
        // Replace http(s): with http(s)4: to use the Camel HTTP4 endpoint.
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(url);
        if (m.matches()) {
            url = m.replaceFirst(m.group(1) + "4:");
        }

        // Try forever until the status code is 200.
        while (getStatusCode(url, context) != 200) {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    }

    private int getStatusCode(String url, CamelContext context) {
        Exchange response = template.request(url + "?method=GET&throwExceptionOnFailure=false", new Processor() {
            @Override public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                // No body since this is a GET request.
                exchange.getIn().getBody(null);
            }
        });

        return response.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, Integer.class);
    }

}
```

Notes:

1. Note the `throwExceptionOnFailure=false` option. An Exception will not be raised, therefore the loop will execute until the condition is true.
2. Inside the bean, I'm looping forever until the HTTP status is 200. Of course, your logic will be different.
3. Between attempt and attempt, I'm sleeping 5000ms.
4. I'm assuming the URL to ping is in the body of the incoming JMS message. I'm replacing the leading `http(s):` with `http(s)4:` in order to use the [Camel HTTP4 endpoint](https://camel.apache.org/http4.html).
5. Performing the pinging inside the TX guarantees that the message will only be consumed once the ping condition is true (in this case HTTP status == 200).
6. You might want to introduce a desist condition (you don't want to keep trying forever). Maybe introduce some backoff to not overwhelm the other party.
7. If either Camel or the broker goes down within a retry cycle, the message will be automatically rolled back.
8. Take into account that JMS transactions are `Session`-bound, so if you want to start many concurrent consumers (`concurrentConsumers` JMS endpoint option), you'll need to set `cacheLevelName=CACHE_NONE` for each thread to use a different JMS `Session`.

Comment: Nice approach, always good to come from different angles.  
So I'm looking for unlimited retries when pinging the URL, although saying that these things can change so need to keep that in mind.
However Webshere is the queue in question so need to investigate the re-delivery options that are open to me. 
Have found some reading to digest here http://tmielke.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/error-handling-in-camel-for-jms.html about that.

Comment: Although saying that and after a bit of investigation there is already a re-delivery policy in place.  And it's to deal with a message that we can't deliver or process (obviously) and set to retry 3 times.
Thus the redeliver approach is not what we need, so really the polling process needs to be that, a separate process to poll the URL even before we even think about picking up from the queue.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the WMQ part in your original post. JMS queue consumers cannot peek or selective consume individual messages. You could use a JMS QueueBrowser, but you'd also need a Consumer to actually remove the message from the queue.

That's why I think you need to explore JMS transactions (TX). The idea is that you consume the message within a TX and try the URL. If successful, Camel would commit the TX and the message would be removed. Otherwise you'd start a retry cycle within the TX, so the TX would remain outstanding, until it's either rolled back (retries desisted) or committed.

Comment: @enkor I've edited my answer to provide you with an alternative version ;-)

Comment: managed to get a working example.  Although not based on relying on the roll back situation, it gave me food for thought, and I can see where it is useful and perhaps down the line I may need to use it. 
But have posted an answer based on the solution I eventually came up.
So just to say thanks for getting my head straight and into the mood for proper investigation.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a bit of difficulty figuring out exactly what you want to do, but it appears to me that you want to consume data from an endpoint on an interval.  For this the best pattern is a polling consumer: http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html

The error you are currently receiving is because you have two consumers both trying to read from the "direct://pingRoute"  If this was intended you could change the direct to a seda://pingRoute  so its an in memory queue your data will be in.